# iOS 7 : Selecting a specific object from a json response

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, ios7

I have a a json response that looks something like this:

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "status_code": 200,
    "active": {
        "owned": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "name": "Chd Home",
                "type": "home",
            },
            ...
        ],
        "shared": [
            {
                "id": "3",
                "name": "Ram's home",
                "type": "home",
            },
            ...
        ]
    },
    "deactivated": {
        "owned": [
            {
                "id": "2",
                "name": "Home",
                "type": "home",
            }
        ]
}
```

I'm following the tutorial by Ray Wanderlich here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5, **this part of the code specifically**:

```
- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {
NSError* error;
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                      JSONObjectWithData:responseData //1
                      options:kNilOptions
                      error:&error];

NSArray* latest = [json objectForKey:@"active"]; //2    
NSLog(@"items: %@", latest); //3
}
```

Now when I want an object for key "active", I used this `NSArray* latest = [json objectForKey:@"active"];` and get the data in the latest array, but when I want only the objects under **found**, I use this `NSArray* latest = [json objectForKey:@"found"];` but the contents of latest are **(null)**

Is there something I'm missing here? How can I access sub-objects of the json array? Like owned and shared in this case. Moving forward I'd like to create different objects for **active > owned**, **active > shared**, **deactivated > owned**, and so on.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you need is to go deeper in hierarchy of the json data dictionary to get the data.

Try this `[[json objectForKey:@"active"] objectForKey:@"owned"]` for getting data for active and owned. and just like so you can get for deactivated

Comment: Thanks! That was quick! :) Btw, what if there are three or four levels? How does one traverse through those to select a specific sub-object? Can you please share an example of that scenario?

Comment: Nevermind. I got it. I thought they were different declarations for different levels.

Comment: @Angad Still, active is a dictionary not an array.

Answer (score 2):

Fist, `active` is a dictionary, not an array. And you should check for the error.

To get `active` and `owned` do this

```
- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {
    NSError* error = nil;
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization
                  JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                  options:kNilOptions
                  error:&error];
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        return;
    }

    NSDictionary *active = json[@"active"];    
    NSLog(@"active: %@", active);
    NSArray *owned = latest[@"owned"];
    NSLog(@"owned: %@", owned);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 "active": {
        "owned": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "name": "Chd Home",
                "type": "home",
            },
            ...
        ],
        "shared": [
            {
                "id": "3",
                "name": "Ram's home",
                "type": "home",
            },
            ...
        ]
    },
```

The active element is a `dictionary` since it is `{` started , you can refer to http://www.json.org/ on information what each symbol stands for

Now the active element is a dictionary, so first you have to get the dictionary object for the `active` key and traverse it to get the inner objects of that dictionary

```
NSDictionary* latest = [json objectForKey:@"active"]; // this will give you the dictionary
```

and the element in the latest will be

```
"owned": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Chd Home",
        "type": "home",
    },
    ...
],
"shared": [
    {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "Ram's home",
        "type": "home",
    },
    ...
]
```

Now get the array for the key `owned` as owned starts with `[` and that is what you want so

```
NSArray *owned = latest[@"owned"];
```

this will give you

```
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Chd Home",
        "type": "home",
    },
    ...
```

this part

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Thanks a great explanation too. Unfortunately there can only be one correct answer, so I marked the first one. :)